# PHP: POST запрос не получает ответа от Paypal

Tags: php, curl, paypal

У меня есть код, который выполняет POST запрос и **успешно** получает ответ от **песочницы** Paypal.

Как только я меню адрес на **живой адрес** Paypal запрос начинает выполняться бесконечно и в итоге ответ не приходит.

Что я делаю неправильно?

```
        // Init cURL
        $request = curl_init();

        // Set request options
        curl_setopt_array($request, array
        (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array
            (
                'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
                'tx' => [$GET['tx']],
                'at' => $this->token,
            )),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
            // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
            // CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
        ));

        // Execute request and get response and status code
        $response = curl_exec($request);
        $status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($request);

        var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить такие параметры

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $sslcert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);  //0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  //0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
```

Ваш хост работает через https?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге заработал вот такой код:

```
        if (isset($GET['tx'])) {
        $query_data = [
            'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
            'tx' => $GET['tx'],
            'at' => $this->token
        ];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PayPal');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query_data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Как понимаю дело было в SSL